# Variable wavelength LED

Tags: visible-light, wavelength, light-emitting-diodes

Does there exist a type of LED (or other type of light source) that can change it's wavelength depending on the current/voltage it receives on a second wire? If not, would something like this even be possible?

Comment: Back as a young aspiring electronics guy I would play with LEDs.  By turning up the voltage you could get a red LED to turn orange, and then yellow...  Continuing onward turned it black and it wouldn't work again (sigh).  However, there are bi-directional LEDs that are two LEDs of opposite polarity in parallel.  Biasing it one way gives one color, reversing the polarity gives another.  Applications involve red/green panel indicators.

Comment: Would [electronics.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: @JonCuster Even more and it becomes an NED (noise emitting diode). The color change is mostly due to self-heating of the die changing the band-gap energy. Dunk it in LN2 and the color changes the other way.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany - and if you put too much current through it will become an SED - smoke emitting device...